# Schur's orthogonality relations on the symmetric Group $S_3$

Tags: functions, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, orthogonality

I have the following proposition which I have to show through an example of the symmetric group $S_3$:

Proposition. Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $\varphi^{(1)}, \ldots, \varphi^{(s)}$ be a complete set of representatives of the equivalence classes of irreducible representations of $G$ and set $d_{i}=\operatorname{deg} \varphi^{(i)}$. Then the functions
$$
\left\{\sqrt{d_{k}} \varphi_{i j}^{(k)} \mid 1 \leq k \leq s, 1 \leq i, j \leq d_{k}\right\}
$$
form an orthonormal set in $L(G)$ and hence $s \leq d_{1}^{2}+\cdots+d_{s}^{2} \leq|G|$.

I don't know how to prove that this applies on the following example :
The trivial Representation $\varphi^{(1)}$ which sends every element to $[1]$;

The Signum $\varphi^{(2)}$ i.e.  $(12) \mapsto[-1]$ and $(132) \mapsto[1]$;

The standard representation $S_3$, $\varphi^{(3)}$: $(1) \mapsto\left[\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right],(12) \mapsto\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right],(13) \mapsto\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right]$, $(23) \mapsto\left[\begin{array}{cr}-1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right],(123) \mapsto$ $\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{array}\right]$ and $(132) \mapsto\left[\begin{array}{cc}-1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right]$

How do I show the orthogonality of the functions of $\varphi^{(3)}$ ?

Comment: For context: 

G is a group, L(G) its group algebra with the inner product defined by
$$
\left\langle f_{1}, f_{2}\right\rangle=\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} f_{1}(g) \overline{f_{2}(g)} .
$$

Comment: (Schur orthogonality relations). Suppose that $\varphi: G \longrightarrow U_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\rho: G \rightarrow U_{m}(\mathbb{C})$ are inequivalent irreducible unitary representations. Then:
1. $\left\langle\varphi_{i j}, \rho_{k \ell}\right\rangle=0$;
2. $\left\langle\varphi_{i j}, \varphi_{k \ell}\right\rangle=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 / n & \text { if } i=k \text { and } j=\ell \\ 0 & \text { else. }\end{array}\right.$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community how do I define the functions $$
\left\{\sqrt{d_{k}} \varphi_{i j}^{(k)} \mid 1 \leq k \leq s, 1 \leq i, j \leq d_{k}\right\}
$$ for $\varphi^{(3)}$ and how do I show their orthonormal relation?

Comment: *Edit your post to include context.*

Comment: Something is off in your definition. The inner product in particular seems to involve products of incompatible types of matrices. Orthogonality of representations is often described using their *characters*, i.e. the traces of the matrices.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The inner product does not involve the product of matrices, it involves the product of matrix coefficients which are treated as complex-valued functions on $G$. Wikipedia calls this the ["coordinate statement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations#Coordinates_statement) of Schur orthogonality, and it does appear often as well.

Comment: OP, you need to use unitary representations for the matrix coefficients to be orthogonal. Your irrep is not unitary as written. Pick a unitary basis and apply change-of-basis to all six matrices. Then you verify the matrix coefficients are orthogonal *directly* - you just calculate the inner product, and see that you get $0$.

Comment: Thanks @runway44. I should have guessed/recalled that much.